# ¿Cómo se agregan comentarios a un commit de Git?

Tags: git, github

Ejemplo de lo que busco crear:

```
fix the router 

implement the new controller to:
- index all data
- store a new Oficinista
- edit an Oficinista by ID
```

Lo que me resulta a mi:

```
fix the router
```

Con comentario me refiero a todo la descripción que se le puede agregar al titulo de un *commit*, se que esto se puede hacer cuando uno agrega archivos manuales en *Github* (Por ejemplo, cuando se agrega una licencia, aparece la opción de agregar un titulo y una descripción).

¿Se pueden agregar comentarios usando comandos de Git? yo suelo usar:

```
git commit -m "el mensaje o titulo del commit"
```

Pero ¿Cómo agregarle los comentarios a un commit por comandos?

Comment: en teoria, si solo haces `git commit` te salta tu editor preconfigurado. Ahi puedes escribir lo que quieras (con saltos de linea incluido)

Comment: escribe `git commit -m "mensaje` luego salto de línea y sigue con `blabla` y termina con `final"`. Nótese las comillas abiertas que solo cierro al final del todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para enviar múltiples líneas en un mensaje se puede realizar de las siguientes maneras:

### Método 1: múltiples parámetros

```
git commit -m "fix the router" -m "implement the new controller to:" -m "- index all data" -m "- store a new Oficinista"
```

### Método 2: Parámetro único

Escribes  `git commit -m "` y sin cerrar comillas te permite presionar la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> para agregar saltos de línea y escribir un único mensaje, este método funciona en *Linux* y *Windows PowerShell*.

> En *cmd* no permite agregar saltos de line mientras escribes para ese caso utiliza el método 1.

### Método 3: no agregar parámetro

Si escribes `git commit` sin el parámetro `-m` y presionas la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> git abrirá un editor de texto en consola y te colocara un resumen de los cambios por defecto, personalmente es el método que mas recomiendo.